# DRF - Set max and min value of a Serializer field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've a serializer where I need to set the min and max value. Currently, this is how I do.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        extra_kwargs = {
            'amount': {'min_value': 10000, 'max_value': 60000},
        }
```

This works fine, but I don't want to hardcode it, ie I want to fetch it from the DB, just in case the value changes.

I've 2 models.

1)  `Category` which has min & max value in it.

2) `Products` which has `amount` and `category` as a FK. The amount entered should be within the range of `min-max`.

**How can this be achieved?**

For eg:-

Anything of this sort.

```
extra_kwargs = {
                'amount': {'min_value': Category.min, 'max_value': Category.max},
}
```

Comment: I don't think I understand. Do you want to use `ProductSerializer` for creating new Products? But you have multiple Categories and would like to make sure that when someone adds a new Product to a Category, the product's amount will fit in the range of this particular category?

Comment: Yes..This is what I meant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe overriding `validate` method is the best option. Because there you have access to the category value.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate(self, data):
         category = data['category']
         amount = data['amount']
         if not (category.min_value < amount < category.max_value):
             raise serializers.ValidationError('Invalid amount blah blah blah...')

         return data

    ...
```

Comment: That's what I'd do too, see [Object-level validation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation) in docs

Answer (score 7):

The new version of DRF from 3.5.0 has a fix for this issue, 
now you can use `max_value` and `min_value` in your integer field.

Like this

```
amount = serializers.IntegerField(required=False, min_value=10000, max_value=60000)
```